# Валентность глаголов

Tags: синтаксис, глаголы, словосочетания

Как определять цифру валентности? В Википедии написано, что у безличных глаголов валентность нулевая, однако безличный глаголы могут вступать в синтаксические связи: знобит (кого?) меня, дождило (до каких пор?) до полудня. Ещё там написано, что у глагола купить валентность 4 - кто, что, у кого, за сколько. Однако можно задать вопросы: где, при чём (при наличии тысячи рублей), куда (купить в дорогу), зачем (купить лук для салата) и т. Д. Валентность минимум 8. Так какие критерии существуют для определения валентности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строгого формального критерия нет. Но очевидно, что в такой постановке речь идет об обязательной валентности - и в её явном проявлении. Связи, проявляющиеся лишь в определенных контекстах не могут служить основанием для подсчета валентности, ибо таких связей можно придумать неограниченно. Даже к глаголам типа "спать": на чем спать, в чем спать, с кем спать... Это все связи, в валентности не учитываемые.

> Однако можно задать вопросы: где, при чём (при наличии тысячи рублей), куда (купить в дорогу), зачем (купить лук для салата) и т. Д. Валентность минимум 8. Так какие критерии существуют для определения валентности?

Нет, это все случайные, лежащие за пределами минимально-необходимого объема актантов действия "купить". Валентность "купить" - 2, 3 или 4 ("за сколько" и даже "у кого" можно считать необязательным: "он захотел есть и купил пирожок"). А так-то можно придумать много всякого. "Кому купил", "зачем купил", "в связи с чем купил": *В магазине у знакомой продавщицы он за пятьсот рублей купил жене к празднику бутылку вина..." - сколько фантазии хватит*.

Answer (score -1):

В русском языке безличные глаголы бывают авалентными и одновалентными в зависимости от семантического типа.  К авалентным относятся безличные глаголы типа "Светает", "Моросит". Способность их соединяться с сирконстантами ("на улице", "за окном") не меняет суть дела, поскольку валентность определяется способностью присоединять к себе актанты, а не сирконстанты.

Глаголы типа ***"знобит", "лихорадит"*** с семантической точки зрения не являются авалентными: это одновалентные глаголы с субъектным актантом. Во французском языке, на материале которого разрабатывается теория Л. Теньера, они образуют классическую двусоставную фразу.  К безличным Л. Теньер относил лишь фразы первого типа, где подлежащее является псевдосубъектом (фр. il pleut и т.п)

> Сирконстант - слово, относящееся к категории наречия, или группа слов, эквивалентная наречию, иными словами - наречия.

Так в предложении ***"Альфред всегда всюду сует свой нос"имеется два сирконстанта: один — времени ('всегда') и один — места ('всюду').***